# Filters (checkboxes & dropdowns) not updating properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently using a dropdown filter (on DataTables) and I'd like to add some checkboxes on top of that. I tried to use the same class for every single on of the checkboxes to track the changes. The following js code was being used for the dropdown filter.

```js
$('.search-input-select').on('change', function() {
  var i = $(this).attr('data-column');
  var v = $(this).val();
  dataTable.columns(i).search(v).draw();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:50%; margin: 0px auto;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3" class="text-center">Filters</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center align-middle">
      <select class="search-input-select">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="g1">Optiong1</option>
        <option value="g2">Optiong2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center align-middle">
      <select class="search-input-select">
        <option value="">All</option>
        <option value="s1">Options1</option>
        <option value="s2">Options2</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="text-center align-middle">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="icheck1">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="e1">
            <label for="input-2">Optione1</label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding: 0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="0" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option0</small></label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="1" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option1</small></label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="1x" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option1x</small></label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td style="padding: 0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="">
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="4" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option4</small></label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="5" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option5</small></label>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" class="search-input-select" value="21" checked>
            <label for="input-2"><small>Option21</small></label>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

It currently works if I just have the dropdown and it will just update once on every change. With the checkboxes every time I check on something it will update but will ignore the rest. Any suggestions?

Comment: where is your  attr `data-column` in html?

Comment: @SyedMohamedAladeen This was being used based on the DataTables examples

Comment: in your code its like `$(this).attr('data-column')`. so it will search that attribute in the elment which has a class name `search-input-select`

Comment: It gets the correct value each time (so for example when I check/uncheck Optione1 / value "e1" it will get the value) but it won't update properly by keeping the previous options on/off.